# Forbidden 403 response from Google Calendar API while calling from Salesforce Using Server-to-Server

Tags: salesforce, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to insert an event on Google Calendar using REST API, I'm using JWT to get the access token as I don't want user to login into google account to get token. I'd performed below steps, but still getting the error:

1. I've created one service account
2. I'm getting a Token from google to send the request
3. I've shared the calendar with Service Account email address as well.

Please see below code:

```
public class GoogleCalendarSynchronization {

    public static void addEvent (){
        String accessToken = GenerateJWTBearerToken.generateTokenforGoogleCalendarServices();
        system.debug(accessToken);
        String createEventEndPoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/';
        String createEventBody = '{' +
            '"attendees": ['+
            '{'+
            '"email": "abc@gmail.com"'+
            '},'+
            '{'+
            '"email": "abc@gmail.com"'+
            '}'+
            '],'+
            '"end": {'+
            '"dateTime": "2019-12-27T03:30:00-07:00"'+
            '},'+
            '"start": {'+
            '"dateTime": "2019-12-27T03:30:00-06:00"'+
            '},'+
            '"summary": "Appointment has been confirmed..!!",'+
            '"location": "TEST",'+
            '"sendUpdates": "all"'+
            '}';
        //system.debug(createEventBody);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse HttpRes = new HttpResponse();

        httpReq.setEndpoint(createEventEndPoint);
        httpReq.setMethod('POST');
        httpReq.setBody(createEventBody);
        httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
        try{
            HttpRes = http.send(httpReq);
            if(HttpRes.getStatusCode() == 200){
                String response = HttpRes.getBody();
                system.debug(response);
                Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);
                system.debug(responseMap.get('id'));
                system.debug('calendar is saved successfully..!!');
            }else{
                String errorMessage = 'Unexpected Error while communicating with Google Calendar API. '
                    +'Status '+HttpRes.getStatus()+' and Status Code '+HttpRes.getStatuscode();
                system.debug(errorMessage);
            }
        }   catch(system.Exception e){
            System.debug('#### Exception Executed : '+e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString() + ' ' +e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) are you passing to generate the credentials? Could you post the whole error message?
Yo need to include one of the scopes necessary for [this method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).
Also is there any reason why you are not using the Google API directly?

Comment: body.writeStringField('scope', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

Comment: How can I use Google API directly? Am I still missing any steps?